# sqoop export to mysql fails

Tags: mysql, hadoop

My scoop export from VM with CentOS to mysql on windows is failing with

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqlimport": error=2, No such file or directory.

My sqoop export command is

sqoop export --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.168.1/test --username root --password root123 --table marksheet --direct --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/marksheet --input-fields-terminated-by '\001'

My Import from mysql (windows) to centOS is successful though.

sqoop import --verbose --fields-terminated-by ',' --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.168.1/test --username root --password root123 --table student --hive-import --create-hive-table  --hive-home /home/training/hive --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --fields-terminated-by ',' --hive-table studentmysql

I have checked in the internet, did not get much help. Any help please...

Comment: First thing you should know is your target databse installed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution myself from the error...

I had to install mysql in my VM using yum install mysql.

The export works then...